# odoo 8 multiple page navigation controller

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-view

I have created a module in odoo 8. The purpose of module is to create a page with a link to another page. i mean at first the main template is rendered and then there is a link to sub page. everything works fine till the main page. i have controllers.py, models.py, views(default.xml). in my **openerp**.py the value of 'data' : 'views/default.xml'. 
The controller is :

```
@http.route('/test/', auth='public')
def index(self, **kw):
    return http.request.render('test.main',{ 'root':'/test' })

@http.route('/test/sub', auth='public')
def sub(self, **kw):
    return http.request.render('test.sub',{ 'root':'/test' })
```

in my template, u have two ids ( namely main and sub )

```
<openerp>
  <data>
       <template id='main'>
           <div class='body'>
                 test body 
                 click to go to next page : <a t-attr-href = "#{ root }/sub">Next Page</a>
           </div>
           <div class='footer'>
                 test footer 
           </div>
       </template>

       <template id='sub' inherit_id="main">
           <xpath expr="//div[@class='body']" position="replace">
           <div class="page">
               replaced data
           </div>
           </xpath>
       </template>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Now when i run this code, i am seeing the main page already replaced not with link. the body is replaced by default. 
But i want that the body should be replaced when clicked on the link for sub page.

I am novice in odoo, so don't know anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Xpath do it work just after the updation of module( not at the
>   time of rending the template )

just use  **t-if** in that case,Like:

```
< t t-if ="not show_tab"> // original data </t>


< t t-if ="show_tab"> // replaced data </t>
```

render the `keyword:show_tab` from your controllers.

One more thing it's my personal suggestion ,don't create two controller for just replacing a tab.

> **A single controller can handle multiple
>   route in odoo** .Please try to follow the concept of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thanks Prakash, basically my problem was that i want to create my own user interface in the place where tree / list view data are there, so was thinking to create whole page design instead. Can you guide me how to create own ui, where there is form or list / tree view items. i mean not to touch sidebar and header bar

Comment: you can take the reference of odoo9 "website_portal.account" template , and read the bootstrap reference http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables

Comment: Hi Prakash, I basically wants to navigate to different template which will inherit the base template ( main) and replace the content of body. Moreover it will also have data from different model which will be passed from controller. thats why i need it to be navigated when clicked, not replaced by default